# How can you generate a Makefile from an Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, makefile

I want to generate a Makefile from an existing Xcode project on the Mac. Specifically, an existing iPhone, Objective-C program on the Mac.

I found [PBToMake](http://members.bellatlantic.net/%7Evze35xda/software.html), but it looks like it is for Xcode 2.1 and when I tried using it, it did not work for an Xcode 3.1 project.

Comment: Why do you want to generate a makefile? Saying so might help get you a better answer.

Comment: This question comes up when I do a google search, and my goal is to build a c++ project on linux.

Answer (score 6):

GNUStep provides '[pbxbuild](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Pbxbuild)' to convert a .xcodeproj file into a GNUMakefile.

**UPDATE:** [pbxbuild is now deprecated](http://gnustep.8.n7.nabble.com/pbxbuild-is-now-deprecated-td24464.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's not an automated way of generating a Makefile, but I found it at least gets a list of source files that are built for a target.

I'm using Xcode 4.0.2 in this case..

- select the project top node
- select the target in the target list.
- Choose "Build Phases"
- Open the "Compile Sources"
- Select one of the source files
- PRess Command-A to select all
- Press Command-C to copy
- Paste in your favorite text editor and Regex away to restructure.

The pasted output is FULL pathnames to each source file.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode does not support generating a Makefile from a project. If you just want to build your project outside of the IDE, check out the `xcodebuild` command-line tool.

Comment: This looks like it builds a project, but doesn't convert an existing project to a standard makefile like the questioner asked.  Am I mistaken in this? If so, would you mind editing editing your answer to include how you can use xcodebuild to generate the makefile?

Comment: It doesn't generate a makefile - there isn't a way to do so. Usually when I've heard people ask "How do I generate a makefile?" it's because they want to build their project from the command line, and just start out assuming that's the way to do so.

Comment: -1 because you didn't answer the original question and just assumed that the asker wanted to build from a CLI. I am looking for Xcode->Makefile converters because I want to try to build a project on Linux using GNUStep. Please don't assume the OP accidentally posed a question he didn't mean, or if you're going to, at least be explicit in the answer text that you are doing so.

Comment: Did you see the part where I asked the OP - two years ago - to clarify why they wanted to generate a Makefile?

Comment: ...so? You still provided an answer that was irrelevant to the original question. It is nice that you helped some, but as I stated above, it would have been better if you had been explicit and said "This doesn't build a makefile, but if you just want to build from the CLI instead of Xcode..."

Comment: @jeffcook2150 I know this was more than nine years ago but honestly you were far too extreme for this. You give all that emotion over the complaint you have? I feel sorry for people like you. So they didn't exactly answer the question. Doesn't mean it has no value to anyone though. Maybe (I don't know nor do I care) they didn't have the rep to comment. And you replied two years later as if Chris did a horrible thing. Well he didn't. He added something and you had a go at him over that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mfg](http://freshmeat.net/projects/mfg/?topic_id=46). It is template based and I think (I haven't played with it too much) you could get it to generate a suitable makefile.